# Simplest example of Select2 doesnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

i'm trying to use Select2 select boxes, but it doesnt work on my page. My js skills is poor, so I try to do simplest example. I'm using bootstrap library. Whole code looking like:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pl">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8_polish_ci">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../inc/bipro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
       <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <br>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                   select2
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
         <select class="aaaa form-control">
          <option value="">wybierz</option>
          <option value="1">banany</option>
          <option value="2">cytryny</option>
          <option value="3">jabłka</option>
         </select>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.aaaa').select2();
    });
    </script> 
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: You didn't include jquery which is a requirement for `bootstrap` AND `select2`

Comment: Got `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
` before `popper.js` and still doesnt working

Comment: Put it first of all scripts. The order of the script tags is really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't including jQuery which is required for both Bootstrap and Select2.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Make sure jQuery is imported before Bootstrap and Select2

You're missing the `name=""` property on your `select`. I'd also rename that class to something that makes sense, like `js-select`

```
<select class="js-select form-control" name="fullnames">
    <option value="0">wybierz</option>
    <option value="1">banany</option>
    <option value="2">cytryny</option>
    <option value="3">jabłka</option>
</select>
```

Then your script will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-select').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine!